# npm install gets stuck at fetchMetadata on Windows 10

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, npm-install

[image: error message]

The message was displayed and nothing else happened afterwards...
I'm not sure why it's doing that

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have correct access rights to the dependancies defined in package.json file. If you are using ssh key to access dependency from some code repository like GitHub bitbucket or gitlab, then your ssh key is loaded and defined in code repository as well.

Comment: I am actually trying to run this locally, i'm not sure how to check if my dependencies are fine or not however this is what my package.json file looks like:
(added an image to the main post)

Comment: I suggest you to post the code instead of image, If you can share the code through git hub or Gist I will have a look and will get back.

Comment: Ditto. Make sure to ssh-add your credentials to ssh-agent.